# Why doesn't this print the times tables?

Tags: python

```
Number=int(input('Give me a number :'))
count=1
print(str(count)+'*'+str(Number)+'='+str(count*Number))
while count<10 :
count=count+1
```

How do I display a chosen timetable by using condition controlled loops ?

Comment: First of all, fix your indentation. Then, tell us exactly what your output should look like. What is a 'chosen timetable'?

Comment: You probably want your print statement inside the loop.

Comment: Maybe the print should be inside the while? It's not really clear what your asking for.

Comment: And even then you'll only get one row of data. If you really want a times table, you'll need a second loop to add columns.

Comment: Firstly it won't let me use Tab for indentation.Secondly the chosen timetable would be what the user enters , that's why I ask 'Give me a Number'.Thirdly shall I put the 'print' line between the while statement ?

Comment: @MattCremeens How do I do that please ?

Comment: @CodingNoob please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to indent the counting statement.

```
Number=int(input('Give me a number :'))
count=1
print(str(count)+'*'+str(Number)+'='+str(count*Number))
while count<10 :
    count=count+1
```

Further, in order to display your results, you must move line 3 into your loop.
The second and last example I gave you are both fully operational, however the last one is certainly more effective.

```
Number=int(input('Give me a number :'))
count=1
while count<10 :
    print(str(count)+'*'+str(Number)+'='+str(count*Number))
    count=count+1
```

Also, some programming tips. If you want to increase the value of count you could simply type:

```
count+=1
```

But Certainly the best approach would be to use a `for` loop.
Like so,

```
Number=int(input('Give me a number :'))
for i in range(10) :
    print(str(i)+'*'+str(Number)+'='+str(i*Number))
```

Comment: yeah I thought I could use  'count' to make it simpler or print the whole times table from 1 to 12.I already know how to use for loop.But how do I display all the times table as I mentioned.Thank you.   EDIT:your first approach worked.Thank you !

Comment: Well, if you were wanting to display twelve multiplicative sets, you would simply change the while loop to: while count<12:

Comment: Oh, welcome! I still would recommend using a for loop such as "for i in range(1,12)"

Answer (score 0):

You can make a double loop (with correct indentation)

```
import sys
for count1 in range(1,11):
    print("")
    for count2 in range(1,11):
        num = count1 * count2
        if len(str(num)) == 1:
            spc = "  "
        else:
            spc = " "
        sys.stdout.write(str(count1 * count2) + spc)
```

Though my formatting leaves something to be desired. Here I am assuming the table contains only 1 or 2 digit numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.From my name I am just learning coding but when I implemented your code : count was not defined.

Comment: I left off the 1 in `count1`. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Importing `sys` allows you to use `sys.stdout.write`. `len` is a function that returns the length of a string. `spc` is just a variable that tracks the number of spaces that print out between numbers. HTH.